# Which webhosting is suitable for my application?

Tags: php, web, neo4j, web-hosting

I have to host my website. As I new to this deployment, I am not able to understand how should I proceed.

Here are my requirements:

1. I am using Apache
2. I am using PHP 5
3. I am using NodeJS server
4. I am using Java 1.7
5. I am using Neo4j (database)

So what do I do? I have seen at many site they are giving PHP, MySQL but I want Neo4j and NodeJS as well.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site for getting hosting suggestions. Please have a look at the **[faq]**.

Comment: Can you please tell me where should I post this question and branches of stackoverflow ?

Comment: Use a VPS and install everything yourself. You can then decide just on the resources you need (e.g. disk space, RAM).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because hosting recommendations aren't a good fit for the SE network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared hosting is not possible for above requirement.You can use linode for virtual private server.So,you can install and use whatever technologies you want.

Comment: The Ip address given by linode would be static ??

Comment: Yes,you can also configure the static IP(https://library.linode.com/networking/configuring-static-ip-interfaces?format=print)